# Placing text inside fontawesome icon

Tags: font-awesome

I would like to add some text to be stacked inside another icon. Here's my attempt:

```
  <!-- How should I style this to work properly with fa-1x and fa-5x ???? -->
  <span class="fa-stack fa-1x">
     <i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
     <span class="fa fa-stack-1x">31</span>
  </span>
```

Are there any ways this would be correct position when using both fa-1x and fa-5x?

http://jsbin.com/opOwENe/3/edit

Larsi

Comment: There is a great example I found here: http://jsfiddle.net/tagliala/vF78n/ (Uses FontAwesome 3.2.1, but might be enough to point you in the right direction.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it might be best to create a different class for both the container and the text.

Something like this (I forked the fiddle from my comment and updated for FontAwesome 4.0.3:
http://jsfiddle.net/canuk/YzkWs/

```
  .calendar-stack {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: (13em / 14);
        height: 1em;

    .fa-calendar-o,
    .calendar-day {
        position: absolute;
    }

    .calendar-day {
        top: (7em / 8);
        left: (1em / 8);
        width: (11em / 8);
        height: (6em / 8);
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: (8em / 14);
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: (8em / 14);
        text-align: center;
      }
  }
```

And then your HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="calendar-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
  <span class="calendar-day">1</span>
</div>
```

or this for 5x:

```
<div class="calendar-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
  <span class="calendar-day">3</span>
</div>
```

***Updated for 4.3.x***

CSS

```
.calendar-stack {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: (13em / 14);
    height: 1em;

    .fa-calendar-o,
    .calendar-day {
        position: absolute;
    }

    .calendar-day {
        top: (7em / 8);
        left: (1em / 8);
        width: (11em / 8);
        height: (6em / 8);
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: (8em / 14);
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: (8em / 14);
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="calendar-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
  <span class="calendar-day">3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I updated your great example for Font Awesome 4.1 and 4.2. http://codepen.io/baxeico/pen/iogtG